# Access Camera through iPhone Web App

Tags: iphone, html, camera

I understand that it is not quite possible to access webcam through HTML. So how about on the iPhone? Is it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at: http://code.google.com/p/iphone-photo-picker/

This was done by the NextStop guys, and is open sourced under MIT license.  It basically uses an URL scheme to allow you to redirect a web user to a tiny native app long enough to take the picture, and then back to your web app to continue their experience.

I haven't used it yet, but I saw them demo it in a webcast and plan on using it myself when we get our mobile site done enough to incorporate it.

Answer (score 51):

Starting with iOS6, You are able to access the Camera, and Photos using the`<input type="file" />`  input

Comment: The actual code should be <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">.

Comment: But will the picture lay in the gallery? I am thinking have to catch the picture with a local html file.

Comment: Here is sample page using input: http://goo.gl/5VbMh . Access it with your iOS 6 device.

Comment: Can we prevent Choose existing option ? I want the user to take new picture each time this button is clicked. Also can we save it in a New album automatically

Comment: How would we process the image?

Answer (score 3):

No.  You can access the phone through the native API, but not via a web app.

Comment: OK. What about in the future? Is it possible?

Comment: Who knows?  Web apps generally have very limited access to any local resources on the client, mainly for security purposes.  It's possible that HTML5 will provide better access to webcams.

Comment: HTML 5 can now do this, at least for the camera part.