# iPhone URL Schema for Camera

Tags: iphone

I want to launch iPhone Camera from web page. I googled around and came to know that it is possible through URL Schema

I have doubt that after registering URL Schema, how should i submit to AppStore and Are there any built-in URL Schemas for Camera

Please tell me.

Comment: Where did you find that information? I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220423/access-camera-through-iphone-web-app

Comment: That involves opening a 3rd-party app. Is that app available on the App Store? Or do you want to put your own app on the store?

Comment: I want to put my own app on the store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to submit your own app, you can implement a custom URL scheme to launch your app. Your app can then access the camera using standard APIs. If you would like to upload the photo and bring it back to your webpage, the URL scheme can take an extra parameter: another URL your app should load after it uploads the photo. See [this section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW50) of the iOS Application Programming Guide for information about how to implement a custom URL scheme.

Comment: :Thanks, One more question does Apple accept this kind of apps

Comment: I think they will, but that is not a question for Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 4):

There is no url scheme for Camera. [Read Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html) apple documentation.
There are 6 standard schemes :
Mail, Phone, Text, Map, YouTube, iTunes.