# Is there a iOS App URL Scheme for the Camera App

Tags: ios, url-scheme

I found this list of the available ios app URl schemes: https://ios.gadgethacks.com/news/always-updated-list-ios-app-url-scheme-names-0184033/

The camera app is not in this list. Trying camera:// does give a prompt to open the Camera app, however on accepting us errors with "address is invalid".

What is the correct way to open the Camera App on iOS via such an URL scheme?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but please look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13510214/2567725

Comment: The answer is you cannot open that app and the question is why you need that? You have possibility to put camera view into your app using AVCaptureSession.

Comment: I have some application that works with offline QR codes. I want to have a button on my mobile website to open the camera app of the phone. Thanks for the link @olha, but it is from 2012.

Comment: But when you will scan the QR code using Camera app then OS will open it in Safari. So it's kind of weird that on browser you will trigger Camera App and safari will open another card with the value from QR code. Do you think maybe about WebRTC solution? for example https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-qrcode-reader

Comment: thanks @ŁukaszŁabuński I guess using this package or something similar would make sense!

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question, However, there is still no custom URL for the OS camera app and I believe it is about power and control and nothing to do with security. It always amazes me the response of "But why would you want to do that" many time without out the "When you could do this".

But in any case, isn't it good enough that they simply asked for it and assume the why is too complicated or long to list out or for you to understand?

But for me the why is pretty simply. The OS camera app has MANY built in features like filters, overlays, animations, cropping, tilting and stickers to add all of those in a PWA and then also potentially store the result twice (OS gallery/file system as well as PWA cache).

Not to mention ease of use and familiarity to the user on doing all of the above. So the better question is why there is no custom URI to the camera app. Certainly isn't privacy or security because the web app need never get access to the local file system which could simply return the edited or unedited results to the one that invoked it without every giving access to the local file system).

But AFAIK, there still is no custom URI to the mobile IOS cam app in 2024. I have looked and even asked chatGPT whose main excuse is that I am correct that there is no privacy issue but the reason is privacy for handing off arbitrary access to the local file system. Right after I pointed out that it is anything but arbitrary and in any case, no access at all to the local file system since the actual data could be returned and not an open link. opening and selecting a file as is done right now seems way more arbitrary and accessible.