# Use phonegap js to access native functionality without compiling an app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

Does anyone know if it is possible to use phonegap.js to access native functionality like the camera without compiling a mobile app? I would like to use it on a mobile-site and was curious if anyone knew of a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the [PhoneGap Docs](http://www.phonegap.com/start) for each OS it says you need to compile in order to work, so no, you cannot use it on a website to access native functionality. The camera cannot be accessed from a website, it needs to be a native app.

[See this SO post for a possible workaround.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220423/access-camera-through-iphone-web-app) I haven't tested it though. And yes, it still does require a native app to be built.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't possible through any JavaScript interface.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap is a JavaScript to native *wrapper* that maps JavaScript/HTML/css to the mobile platform's native SDK.  Since PhoneGap is only a wrapper, a compilation step is required