# iphone camera access for mobile webpage

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

For the mobile website of a project I need to add a image-uploading button which does allow the access of the Iphone camera.
For example, the user does have his own profile and wants to add an avatar to that, he should have the possibility to make a photo, which is directly uploading to a database. Ive found some scripts where it is possible to access the photo-gallery, but i want to access the camera, which automatically uploads the picture...

> Take a picture and upload

something like that!
Any help is much appreciated,

Greets

Comment: Check this out maybe it can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220423/access-camera-through-iphone-web-app

Comment: We recently did some researches and iphone support camera upload from iPhone 4S IOS6 / Safari

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have iOS 6 or greater you can use the

```
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

Comment: for older you'd need to use some 3rd party library. i've seen one some time ago on Google Code. Just search around.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS < 6, you can always implement an image picker yourself and then inject the captured image data into the html as base64 encoded data.

Take the picture, base 64 encode your captured image data, then,
with jQuery, it should be quite simple:

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$('#imagePlaceholder').attr('src','data:image/png;base64,%@');", base64ImageDataString]];
```