# Use mobile phone camera as a scanner with GWT?

Tags: android, iphone, gwt, barcode-scanner

I m using GWT as a substitute for mobile phone app`s.

Now I need an app that reads from a barcode.

Is it possible to accomplish this using GWT?

Is it possible to do though the web browser at all?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Android 3.0 and iOS6 you can capture an image from the camera using the following in your HTML:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

or:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

You should test to see which of these is more portable to the devices you care about.

See [this answer (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7811843/90848) and [this answer (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12326434/90848) to other questions for more info.

You'd then have to do the image analysis server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a scanner [zbar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/files/) for example and write the Phonegap plugin for android and iPhone. I think that's an easier approach.